# Management session phonegap restful API?

Tags: java, ajax, mobile, cordova

I development currently mobile application in phonegap , i'm begginer in this framework .I talk about context  problem, my mobile application does AJAX request to API restfull in java using Spring , but i dont know hold state session , in the  "/login" operation send json object with identifier device and some  necesary parameters , using  method POST , but for example "/getObjects" using GET method,  and the body  request should be empty, i don know with phonegap can use cookies or some alternatives for have "ID-session"  and send  request to server .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the LocalStorage API that phonegap provides.

Example:

```
window.localStrorage.setItem('KEY','VALUE');
```

then:

```
window.localStorage.getItem('KEY');
```

Full reference here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage

Comment: Thanks a lot for help !!!! , but i have  doubt , if send AJAX request  implicity send 'KEY' in the  request or get explicity  'window.localStorage.getItem('KEY');' and  add   some  header or cookie ?